Closed for wrong reason?
Rationally speaking, should we have a certain style of proof, or evidence, in order to fundamentally change our practices?
... Was closed as needing clarification.
I'm voting to reopen, since I found it quite clear enough as it stood. There was one quibble about normative versus typical, which was answered in the comments; if that's the concern, it would have been kinder to simply edit that answer into the question on the author's behalf.
If it was something else: When VTC for that reason, it really helps to leave a comment explaining what you think needs to be improved. An interest in philosophy does not grant mind reading powers.
I would understand voting to close it as a duplicate of one of the other probability/decision questions that have gone by, though it is just different enough that I decided to answer instead. Or downvoting it as being more a question of personal preference then one philosophy has a principled answer to. But it is unclear why folks thought it was unclear.

There may be a tendency to say "sure, let's go with the reason already selected” if one is inclined to close, rather than considering whether that reason is appropriate. That's a problem with the stack exchange UI; if I am really not sure what bothers me about a question, knowing what others selected might be helpful, but I think it biases the results too strongly toward the first reason given,  and frankly if I don't know my reason  I probably shouldn't be voting to close.

@shindemo: if there's no answer in philosophy, then a minor edit to change the question to ask if philosophy has an answer for this would strike me as  more productive. "Can philosophy address this" is a valid question about philosophy.

It does not seem clear to me which practices he's talking about changing. He says not science, then mentions "going to church" and "everyday concerns" in the same sentence. Is he saying that going to church is an "everyday concern"? What kind of "everyday concern" does he mean? Needs to be more narrow and specific. If he's asking what level of evidence in God makes it ethical to go to church despite not believing in God, he should say that.

It sounds to me as though the linked question is asking whether it is rational for all beliefs to have a justification. If so, that is a question that comes up frequently in one form or another and about which a great deal has been written. I'm guessing that might be a reason for a downvote. The question is not an exact duplicate but it's just a variation on a theme.

@causitive: In comments, he explained that church was an example, not the case he was concerned about. Perhaps an unfortunate example given the sensitivity some folks have about religion, but not inherently an invalid one. Again, the question could have been edited to clarify that once it was flagged. Of course that edit could still be made, and the question reopened... But is has been shown in the discussions of probability, it is possible to explore the question of general principles of confidence without the questioner meeting to specify confidence in what. Unclear, but harmlessly so?

@Bumble: Closure as duplicate could be justified, I think, especially since that close reason includes a pointer to what is being duplicated. Might still be a good idea to comment on other related questions. Might be even better to comment on that first, then decide whether to close as duplicate, so multiple references can be made.

There is an entire field of philosophy, epistemology, for which this is the central question.  The OP shows no indication of being aware of this at all, IE is almost totally unread in philosophy, and has not attempted to remedy that lack, before posting an unresearched and vague question on our SE.  While I have found the VTC campaign to often be in overreach, in this case I am 100% in agreement with closure.

@Dcleve: Your first sentence would have been the start of a good Answer. I can't speak for anyone else,  but given Stack Exchange's mission of being a crowdsourced FAQ site, I would think that is within our mission here to help people learn, and help them learn how to learn. I am almost unread in philosophy myself; if that is to be considered a prerequisite, I am clearly in the wrong place.

Keshlam -- I have put a comment in the OP question, listing the method by which the best of phil of science over the last 3/4 of a century has clarified that epistemology should be done.  It lists Popper, Quine, Kuhn, Lakatos, memeplexes, and consilience as key references that if pursued would lead you and Shindamo to be able to ask better questions on epistemology.

In my own philosophic journey, I realized now many decades ago that "how to know what we know" is a critical question, and I needed to figure out how to do epistemology much better.  Discovering Popper was a key for me, which allowed me to extend empiricism and falsifiability to all of philosophy.  Realizing, however, that memeplexes are strongly resistant to being upended, leading to stable paradigms based on Quine-Duhem, and that falsifiability was falsified, was also key.  One needs to show a memeplex to be "regressive" thru consilience of multiple small falsifications.

@Dcleve: okay. But that still isn't "needing clarification", as I would use the phrase.

If the answer needs to summarize an entire field of philosophy, the question is too broad. Also, there are multiple competing approaches to epistemology. I tried to give you two the hooks to at least follow my path thru that field.  If you need more specific recommendations, Popper's The Unended Quest is a good intro to his thinking, and Conjectures and Refutations takes one into some of his later elaborations on it.  As a democracy advocate, and dualist I loved both The Open Society and its Enemies, and The Self and Its Brain.

@Dcleve:  On other stacks, there is a useful distinction drawn between unclear and needing focus. It sounds like you are saying the latter should have been the close reason.

Yes, if I had been one of the VTC, I would have checked "needs focus".
